# Punctuation for delineating two adjectives

Tags: punctuation

Given the following:

> A “one true arbiter of goodness and badness” would conveniently render
>   the subjective objective instantly.

Should "subjective" and "objective" be delineated by any punctuation?

Comment: What does "conveniently render the subjective objective instantly." mean?

Comment: @Cargill—that which is inherently subjective (i.e. judging what is good and bad) would be made objective (i.e. not a matter of opinion) were there a true arbiter (i.e. a reliable judge) to distinguish between them.

Comment: Hmm ... thanks for that, and nicely poetic. But I shall retain my life-long view that there is precious little in this world that is objective, and it all depends on your POV and stake in the outcome.  Every decision of the highest courts are inherently political!

Comment: To make the sense of "render the subjective objective" clearer, I would consider shifting "instantly" to a position earlier in the sentence: "A 'one true arbiter of goodness and badness' would conveniently (and instantly) render the subjective objective."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both words were acting as adjectives, then you would separate them with a comma as you do the adjectives in the following sentence.

> He was a clean, quiet, polite man.

However, **subjective**, while an adjective, is acting as a noun, *i.e.*, it's a noun adjunct or adjectival noun. Thus, it wouldn't be separated from **objective** as it would if they were two consecutive adjectives.